# How can I preserve Null (DBNull) in Sum in LINQ queries

Tags: vb.net, linq, null, sum

I am trying to perform this query on two DataTables in a DataSet

```
SELECT Totals.accCategory, Totals.ID, Totals.Account, Sum(Totals.Jan) AS Jan FROM (SELECT * FROM Allocated UNION SELECT * FROM Spent) AS Totals GROUP BY Totals.accCategory, Totals.ID, Totals.Account
```

As they are generated in code (in memory) into the DataSet I need to use LINQ thus:

```
Dim t = (From totals In (allocated.AsEnumerable.Union(spent.AsEnumerable)) _
            Group totals By accCategory = totals.Item("accCategory"), ID = totals.Item("ID"), Account = totals.Item("Account") _
            Into g = Group _
            Select New With {Key .accCategory = accCategory, Key .ID = ID, Key .Account = Account, Key .Jan = g.Sum(Function(totals) Totals.Item("Jan"))}).ToList
```

Which fails as there are some instances where there are no records to sum. The Access query returns an empty cell - which is what I want. I can make the LINQ statement work by using `If(IsDbNull(totals.Item("Jan")),0,totals.Item("Jan"))` but then I get 0.00 if the total is zero (which is correct) but also if there are no items to sum (which I don't want)

I have tried `Select New With {Key .accCategory = accCategory, Key .ID = ID, Key .Account = Account, Key .Jan = g.Sum(Function(totals) DirectCast(totals.Item("Jan"), Nullable(Of Decimal)))}).ToList` which doesn't work either.

How can I make .Jan a Nullable(Of Decimal) and accept DBNull as a value??

Thanks
Andy

Comment: -1 Did not read, code is poorly formatted.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but `DefaultIfEmpty` may be what you want.

Comment: Aron - Frankly, how rude. Code is marked as code. Shame when everyone else here is so helpful. Neolisk - thanks, will look.

Comment: I don't think `DefaultIfEmpty` is what I need, I want to preserve the Nulls. I think it may have something to do with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549409(v=vs.100).aspx but I can't make sense of it. Thanks.

Comment: This `Select New With {Key .accCategory = accCategory, Key .ID = ID, Key .Account = Account, Key .Jan = g.Sum(Function(totals As DataRow) As Nullable(Of Decimal)
                                                                                                                            Return Nothing
                                                                                                                        End Function)}).ToList` seems to use the right type of Sum - but when I force it to `Nothing` and inspect the table it still shows 0D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
Dim t = (From totals In (allocated.AsEnumerable.Union(spent.AsEnumerable)) _
            Group totals By accCategory = totals.Item("accCategory"), ID = totals.Item("ID"), Account = totals.Item("Account") _
            Into g = Group _
            Select New With {Key .accCategory = accCategory, Key .ID = ID, Key .Account = Account, Key .Jan = If(g.AsQueryable.Any(Function(totals) totals.Field(Of Nullable(Of Decimal))("Jan").HasValue), g.AsQueryable.Sum(Function(totals) totals.Field(Of Nullable(Of Decimal))("Jan")), Nothing)}).ToList
```